# Titanium app immediate crash on BB10.2

Tags: titanium, blackberry-10, titanium-alloy

I've been developing an app with Titanium, and I've got the app up and running on both iOS and Android.

Today I set up the Blackberry 10 environment to be used with Titanium and tried to compile and deploy to the simulator... It worked! But alas, after a brief peek at the appcelerator splash screen, the app crashes; all without any errors, warnings, or logs of any kind.
I've used telnet to see if there were any logs in the '1000' directory, and the logfile was empty for my app.

From what I've read in appcelerator's documentation and what I've discovered in the Titanium Studio software, Blackberry debugging support is not included.
Further information: I'm using the Parse JS library (not as a titanium module, just as a JS import) and my main window contains a TabGroup.

If anyone has any experience in Titanium for BB10 or insight as to what may point me in the right direction, that would be amazing.

Comment: Could you please tell us which Titanium SDK version are you using? I have seen many many differences between versions, some of them even downgrade functionality in later versions. 

You could try using another version, but if problems persist, please post version. That way is easier for someone to help you.